# Passenger + nginx + rails deployment on aws server error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, nginx, passenger, capistrano3

nginx error log showing the following output:

> [ 2015-06-17 17:52:45.0708 30940/7fdbe8878700 App/Implementation.cpp:303 ]: Could not spawn process for application /www/apps/oddhapok-staging/current: An error occured while starting up the preloader.
>     Error ID: 402cee85
>     Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-tjaWZi.html
>     Message from application:
>
> It looks like Bundler could not find a gem. Maybe you didn't install all the gems that this application needs. To install your gems, please run:
>
> bundle install
>
> If that didn't work, then the problem is probably caused by your application being run under a different environment than it's supposed to. Please check the following:
>
> 1. Is this app supposed to be run as the `deployer` user?
> 2. Is this app being run on the correct Ruby interpreter? Below you will
>            see which Ruby interpreter Phusion Passenger attempted to use.
> 3. Please check whether the correct RVM gemset is being used.
> 4. Sometimes, RVM gemsets may be broken.
>            [Try resetting them.](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Resetting-RVM-gemsets)
>
> -------- The exception is as follows: -------
>
> Could not find i18n-0.6.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

The last is gem not found error. I've added the `gem 'capistrano-bundler'` in my gemfile and require the `capistrano/bundler` in capfile. But still the error exists.

anyone have any idea?

Comment: what's in /tmp/passenger-error-tjaWZi.html? It's complaining about i18n not bundler.

Comment: @Mircea I've search a lot, but surprisingly there is no /tmp/passenger-error-tjaWZi.html file !!!

Comment: probably got purged. try deploying again?

Comment: The issue is fixed. Passenger always links the ruby 2.1.1 version where my application requires 2.2.2. Delete all other rvm rubies except 2.2.2 solves the issue.